# How to include empty directories while building using spring maven plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

my project has an empty folder '**static**' under **src/main/resources** and while using **mvn spring-boot:repackage** '**static**' folder hasn't copied to '**target**' folder, but whenever '**static**' folder contains any file like '**src/main/resources/static/images/asb.jpg**' then the file and it's parent directories are copied to '**target**'. i've gone through **spring-boot-maven-plugin** docs but didn't found any solution.

I've noticed that **maven-build-plugin** has a configuration like below, that can copy empty foldes to **target**. but didn't find any solution for **spring-boot-maven-plugin**.

```
  <configuration>
    <includeEmptyDirectories>true</includeEmptyDirectories> 
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding this plugin configuration `<configuration>
        <addResources>true</addResources>
      </configuration>`?

Comment: @lainatnavi yes i did, but it didn't work.

Comment: The question is why do you need to add an empty directory ?

Comment: @khmarbaise static folder not necessarily empty but it may be empty some times. i just want to know how to handle the scenario when no static content exist.

Comment: If you package an empty directory in your jar file...Then the question came up: For what purpose? You can't change the content inside the jar so from my point of view it does not make sense...maybe you can elaborate a little bit more what exactly the problem is?

Comment: @khmarbaise  First of all i'm creating a war package and i have a controller which takes multipartfile and writes it into static/images folder(which is an empty folder while building the application and doesn't included in war after build). i think i cleaned your doubt.

Comment: How could you write into a static folder while it's running as WAR (inside Tomcat etc.) ? Does not work and should never work (cause how do you locate the folder from within your code?)...Writing something should be done based on an other location which can be configured ....

Comment: @khmarbaise multipartfile.copyTo(Files.createFile(Paths.get(String.format("%s/%s", servletContext.getRealpath("/images"),
multipartfile.getOriginalFileName())));

Comment: Inside a war/jar this will not work cause you don't have a file system in the WAR file ...

Comment: @khmarbaise when you copy .war file to tomcat webapps folder, tomcat will extract it and run the application. i had worked on multiple web applications and i even stored user uploaded images to /static/images/user-directory/image-name.image-extension and i never got any problems. in those web applications war files /static/images folder contains web application logo and other images, but in current webapp, i don't have any images in /static/images, so if someone knows how to include the empty folders then it would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not possible with just `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. But you can include in your pom.xml the **Maven Resources Plugin** and use its `includeEmptyDirs` configuration property:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: i've tried by placing this plugin, but still not working.